# Define Eclipse project encoding as UTF-8 from Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I want to have the encoding of my project's file to be set to UTF-8.

Following [maven FAQ answer](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning), I set the `project.build.sourceEncoding` property to UTF-8. unfortunatly, it has no effect.

Then, by looking at a [m2eclipse JIRA](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-1782), I tried a workaround by defining compiler plugin `sourceEncoding`, but it neither worked, as I try to do that in a separate module parent pom.

Then, what is the solution to ensure my files are all in UTF-8 from maven ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(A bit late) Solution / workaround I'm using to avoid inheriting MacRoman.

```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <additionalConfig>
            <file>
              <name>.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs</name>
              <content>
                <![CDATA[eclipse.preferences.version=1${line.separator}encoding/<project>=${project.build.sourceEncoding}${line.separator}]]>
              </content>
            </file>
          </additionalConfig>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Execute the command below :

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Credits to [Steven Cummings](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/200903.mbox/%3C2E04331034C1794595C880783DA08B58022B45D1@EMAIL03.cerner.net%3E).

Answer (score 3):

Just specifying

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

will do it.

It didn't use to work - hence the other answers - but this was fixed already back in 2011. For more details, see [eclipse bug entry 343927](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=343927).

Answer (score 1):

> Define Eclipse project encoding as UTF-8 from Maven

I don't know if you saw [MNGECLIPSE-1782](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-1782) but this is currently not supported, m2eclipse doesn't derive the project encoding from your POM. You'll have to set up the encoding manually under Eclipse (which can be done globally for the workspace via **Preferences > General > Workspace**).

Comment: So there absolutely no workaround except the tedious manual process of setting file encoding on each Eclipse workspace where one have to work ?

Comment: @Riduidel: Well, the above Jira issue does mention a workaround: *"writing an extension for org.maven.ide.eclipse.projectConfigurators extension point"*.